# C# HttpWebRequest response error (401)

Tags: c#, cookies, .net-core, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

Please excuse me if I look as though I'm doing something stupid here.  I've tried browsing other stack overflow questions for the answer to my issue, yet do not seem to be getting anywhere.

I'm working on a dotnet core MVC application and wanting to return some data from a remote server.  I am using the HttpWebRequest class.

In Fiddler I executed the following using the composer.

[image]

As you can see its a simple GET request with two cookies passed in the header.

This works great and returns me exactly what I need.

I then compose my request in the dotnet world as follows:

```
 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

 request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

 request.CookieContainer.Add(new Cookie("name", "value", "/", "localhost"));
```

(did not include second cookie for purpose of question)

I then call:

```
var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Yet receive 'The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized'

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here? I tried to add the following line of code for testing purposes, but still no luck.

```
request.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
```

All answers appreciated.  Plus as I mentioned, I'm no expert so I could just be doing something daft!

James

Comment: Can you use fiddler to look at the request that is being produced from the C# code? How is it different from the working request you produced in fiddler?

Comment: Is your request url going to localhost? You've set the cookie to only be delivered to the localhost domain.

Comment: Hi @Ed T thanks for your comment.  I did what you said and changed this to the correct domain and...bingo! it worked.  Should have spotted that one!  Turn this into an answer and i'll up vote and mark this as the answer.  James

Comment: Can you post the rest of the controller action?

Comment: @JamesSherburn, glad to help. Answer posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `Cookie` constructor, you are setting the cookie's domain as "localhost" which means it will only be delivered to requests to the localhost domain. It should be set to the domain you are actually sending the request to.

Answer (score 2):

I think your request is defaulting to POST, but your Fiddler example is doing a GET.

Try adding:

```
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding='utf-8'";
```

Comment: Hi @Scrappydog just out of interest I also tried this, yet it didn't make a difference.  The request still processed as a GET.  I guess there is no harm in making this explicit though, so I'm up voting.